# AWS Amplify: onStatusChange then render main page

Tags: javascript, react-native, aws-amplify

I am trying to render the main entry point of my application when an auth status change occurs but when I do try to go to the main entry point of my application I get a blank screen. I'm assuming I can't go to a main page if  it isn't being called within the render function itself? If so, how do I render the main Page of my app when I established signIn?

### index.js

```
class App extends Component {

  /*
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        authState: null,
        authData: null
    }
}
*/
handleAuthStateChange(state) {
  alert(state)
  if (state === 'signedIn') { 
    alert('here');
    return ( // go To Entry point of app
      <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
      <AppWithNavigationState/>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

    render() {
      //const { authState, authData } = this.state;
     // const signedIn = (authState === 'signedIn');


        return (
         <Authenticator hideDefault={true} onStateChange={this.handleAuthStateChange}>
        <Login/>
        </Authenticator>

      );
    }

}
export default App = codePush(App);
```

### Login.js

```
export default class Login extends Component {


    render() {

       const { authState, onStateChange } = this.props;

       if (!['signIn', 'signedOut', 'signedUp'].includes(authState)) {
           alert('login')
        return null;
       }


        return (<View style={styles.container}>

            <View style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
            <Image source={images.icons.LoginImage} style={styles.backgroundImage} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.overlay}>
            <Button iconLeft light rounded style={styles.facebookLoginButton}>
            <Icon style={styles.facebookIcon} name='logo-facebook' />
            <Text style={styles.facebookButtonText}>Login with Facebook</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button rounded bordered light style={styles.loginLaterButton}
            onPress={() => onStateChange('signedIn')}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In Test</Text>
            </Button>


            </View>

            </View>

        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really about rendering and state (and not anything to do with AWS Amplify).  First, set up state in your constructor:

`constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { authState: '' };
}`

Then, your `onAuthStateChange()` becomes:

`onAuthStateChange(newState) {
    if (newState === 'signedIn') {
        this.setState({ authState: newState });
    }
}`

Finally, in your `render()` method, you adjust your rendering so that it does "the right thing" based on your auth state.

`render() {
   if (this.state.authState === 'signedIn') {
        return (<ApolloProvider ...><MyApp/></ApolloProvider>);
    } else {
        return (<Authenticator .../>);
    }
}`

You can abstract this away with a HOC as well (the same way the `withAuthenticator()` HOC from AWS Amplify does it).  Basically, the Authenticator gets displayed initially.  Once the signedIn state is received, the internal component state is updated and that causes a re-render of the component with the rest of your app.

Comment: Thanks but how do you handle auth state when you restart the app? the state would get reset by calling this.setState in the initial constructor method for this class

Comment: Several ways to do it.  I would store the accessToken in a redux store and persist using redux-persist.  On entry into the authenticator, check the expiry date of the accessToken - if not expired, then set state to signed in and register it.

Answer (score 3):

If you resolved it I hope it will help someone else.

I think the following is a better option than using 'onAuthStateChange':

from [Amplify dox](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#using-components-in-react--react-native) :

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
    bypassCache: false  // Optional, By default is false. If set to true, this call will send a request to Cognito to get the latest user data
}).then(user => console.log(user))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

You can add your logic within '.then(user => ...' to add route to your protected pages. Also you can redirect to Login page from '.catch(err => '.

If you include above code within a function and call it from 'componentWillReceiveProps' it should be called every time auth status changes.